# Grub detect wrong version of Windows

Tags: windows, grub

i have a laptop with Windows Vista but Grub detects as Windows 8 no matter what distro i use, Grub always detects my Windows Vista as Windows 8, how can i fix this?

Comment: Just to confirm, is it having problems booting Windows, or is it just the name of the menu option is annoying you?

Comment: Just the name in Grub menu, Windows boots well, not a big issue but it's strange.

Comment: And i will have to do that everytime Grub and os-prober are upgraded?

Comment: @elc79 whenever grub is triggered to update the menu it will overwrite the entries. This can include installing new kernels.

Comment: It's very strange, this happens on a laptop and the recovery partition is detected as Windows Vista, but the main partition is detected as Windows 8.

Comment: Solved, for some reason Windows 8 bootloader was there, i had a Windows 8 in another partition, i though that removing that partition Windows Vista loader will be the default Windows loader again but it wasn't, i had to remove Windows loader entry with EasyBcd and then repair repair the bootloader. After sudo update-grub Windows Vista loader is there.

Comment: Please put amendments in the question.